# Get port and url for project

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get the port and url my project is running on?
I.e if it is running on `7074` for `http://localhost:`, am I able to get that on runtime?

Comment: what project type your running it from

Comment: It's a `netcoreapp3.1`

Comment: do you want to get the port of ur running project? if yes try running this on ur cmd : netstat -a -b.  if you are using visual studio search LaunchSettings.json

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the context of a request, yes, you can use the following:

```cs
var scheme = Request.Scheme; // https
var host = Request.Host.Host; // localhost
var port = Request.Host.Port; // 7074
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net core web application, you can try to use [IServerAddressesFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.features.iserveraddressesfeature?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to get your HostName & Port in Runtime

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    var serverAddressesFeature = app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
    var address = serverAddressesFeature.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
    //this address value is your expect
    //....
}
```